# How to find element of linked list correctly in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I want to evaluate the following: `(eval-expr '(times x x) '((x ((plus y x) ((x 2) (y 3))))))`

This is a lazy evaluation using scheme. I keep getting the following error:

`mcar: expects argument of type ; given 3`

The overall answer is 25, but you have to do that by getting the value of `(plus y x)` and assigning it to the head of the environment. `(plus y x)` is the `caadr` of the above expression and the environment is the `cadadr`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the code looks right.

Line 4 handles this type of case.

```
(define (eval-expr E env)
  (cond
   ((eqv? (car E) 'plus) (apply + (eval-params (cdr E) env)))
   ((eqv? (car E) 'times) (apply * (eval-params (cdr E) env)))
   ((eqv? (car E) 'divide) (apply / (eval-params (cdr E) env)))
   ((eqv? (car E) 'minus) (apply - (eval-params (cdr E) env)))
   (else '()))) ;  confused - return  ()

(define (eval-params E env)
  (if (null? E) '()
      (cons (eval-expr (car E) env)
            (eval-params (cdr E) env))))
```

Comment: Need much more context here.  Are you working from the PLAI textbook? EOPL? Is this supposed to be a lazy language? Did your instructor tell you to use set-car! ?

Comment: It's in scheme and my instructor told me to use (set-car! L v) or (set-cdr! L v) for this example.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, it looks like you're implementing a lazy language where the environment holds promises, and when a promise is evaluated, you're supposed to mutate the environment to contain the new value.

My recommendation: design a couple of helper functions. First: a function that accepts a symbol representing a variable name and an environment, and returns the value of that variable, *with the side effect of mutating the environment to contain the updated binding*. Within this, you'll probably want another helper function that accepts a single binding, evaluates its right-hand-side, and then mutates it to contain the new value.

Be sure to *TEST* these helper functions thoroughly.

Comment: I added the necessary help functions, but it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: Umm... you haven't given me any information. How can I possibly help you?

Comment: Let's be more specific. Can you show me one of your test cases for the function that accepts a single binding, evaluates its right-hand-side, and then mutates it?